# How do I check a condition has been true for 5 seconds?

Tags: c++

I want to check if a condition has remained true for 5 seconds and, if so, perform an action.

Something like...

```
while(1){
    // other code here
    if( cond1 == cond2 ){
        (start 5 second timer){
            timerFinished = true;
        }
    } else {
        reset timer;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

I did wonder if something like this would work...

```
while(1){
    long myTimer = 0;
    if( cond1 == cond2 ){
        myTimer = myTimer + 1;
    } else {
        myTimer = 0;
    }

    if( myTimer > 100000 ){ //arbitary figure equivalent to 5 seconds in program cycles
        timerFinished = true;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

But I thought there must be a better way of achieving this.

I also wondered about the "sleep" function but it seems that this pauses the program to go off and do other stuff rather than achieving the effect that I want?

Comment: Note that if you check some condition at the beginning and at the end of some time interval, that does not necessarily mean that the condition remained true throughout the whole interval.

Comment: You need an additional variable to be set when the condition once changes in the interval. Else you don't know if it changed more than once, e.g. back to true again.

Comment: What owns the process that causes the condition to change? Is it something in your program?

Comment: @DanielLangr wouldn't the second example I posted cover that though? Because if the condition becomes 'untrue' then it resets the timer to zero. Only if the condition has remained true for the full amount of time (program cycles) would it give me the result? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Thanks for your comment. See my comment above to DanielLangr. I'm probably missing something here though..

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, the conditions are controlled by things happening in the program. I need a way of knowing if the two conditions are equal for a 'rough' amount of time (of around 5 seconds or so). I'm from a PLC programming background where we have timers etc but I have no clue how to achieve this in C++. Thanks :-)

Comment: It seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/455871). What problem are you really trying to solve? What is `cond1` and `cond2`? What sets their values? Are they set asynchronously (e.g, by other threads)?

Comment: Does this have to be thread-safe?

Comment: If the condition is controlled by your program, I would recommend to identfy all sources that can change your condition. When the condition potentially changed, then check, if it actually _has_ changed, and if it has changed you could set a timestamp or something. This is in my eyes the only possibility to achieve this.

Comment: @DanielLangr super churill I can see that the answer to this question is FAR more complicated than I was naively expecting. I honestly thought there would be some way of storing the 'real time' and then just comparing it to 'now' or some sort of 'timer' function that I could use. I'll go back to the drawing board and look at other ways to achieve this as I feel like I'm trying to read the last page of a murder novel without understanding the rest of the book. Thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: @JohnT Setting up timers and comparing them to "now" is pretty straight forward using `std::chrono`. The problem with your question is something else, as you might have noticed by now: The condition could change for a very short time **between checks**. This means, you cannot guarantee the condition did not change by just checking repeatedly.

Comment: @eike yes, you're correct. I'm from a PLC programming background and this would be exceptionally simple in that environment due to the nature of how the PLC scans. However, I'm understanding the difference now and the extra dimensions involved in achieving this in C++. All in all, this question has been a great learning experience. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition can only occur in a:

**1) Multithreaded environment:** The state change will not happen in a single threaded circumstance. See below snippet to realize such a scenario.

**2) Triggered by external hardware:**  Use hardware interrupt triggered by edge level changes without the need for polling.

```
atomic<bool> cond;

bool PressedFor5Sec() {

    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    bool flag = true;
    while (chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() < start + chrono::seconds(5)) {
        if (!cond) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    return flag;
}

int main() {
    cond = true; // initial state

    auto simulator = thread([]() {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3)); // state change time delay
        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(6));
        cond = false; // state change 
    });

    bool result = PressedFor5Sec();

    cout << (result ? " Pressed for 5 sec" : " Press interrupted") << endl;

    simulator.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. There's some really interesting concepts in there that I will now read up on. Thanks again :-)